# How to add overflow to Zurb Foundation drop down menu?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have sticky top bar with dropdown menu. The menu contains many elements so in limited height screen size the rest of elements could not be access. I tried to add overflow to the ul of the menu as the the following:

```
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <!-- Right Nav Section -->
        <ul class="right">     
          <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#"><?php echo lang('Choose Source');?></a>
<!-- Adding overflow -->
            <ul class="dropdown" style="overflow: scroll">
```

However, it just render a disabled scroll bar as the screen shot showing:

[image]

Is there any solution or alternative workaround?

**I use Foundation 5.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your CSS just shows a disabled scroll bar after setting `overflow: scroll;` that is indicative of not setting the height on the object. Since you are dealing with Foundation top-bar you will need to set the height and use `!important` in order to overwrite their styling of `height: auto !important`.

Since you are open to alternatives I suggest transforming your long drop down into multiple columns. I have created a codepen example [here](http://codepen.io/adam-huffman/full/adbd8715f7eb5d652fe86b43f3cca0cc).

**Option One**: Adds a scroll bar like you were originally wanting to accomplish. It is doable, but I not certain it lends itself to a good user experience. *Orange arrow point to scrollbar.*

[image: Option One]

**Option Two**: Is a simple two column that uses the dropdowns natural float left, so there is little additional markup. Option two may have a downside depending on how you want the reading order to be. *Orange arrow signifying reading order using left to right with Option Two.*

[image: Option Two]

**Option Three**: Is a bit more markup but it keeps the reading order down column one then down column two. *Orange arrow signifying reading order using left to right with Option Three.*

[image: Option Three]

Of course for both Option Two and Option Three you can extend it out to be as many columns as you want and you will need a media query to be sure the styles only affect screen sizes above your breakpoint.

If I have misunderstood your question please feel free to clarify and provide a [codepen](http://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to your PHP generated HTML.

If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I preferred the option number 1. It is  more simpler and as I tested it, it does not corrupt the responsive deign in small screens. I did not tested the other two options yet. I just added inline style to the `<ul class="dropdown">` just as `style="height: 260px !important; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;"`